# Partial content request in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, nginx, partial

There are plenty of posts about Partial content issues with Chrome. But I'm really stuck and any suggestion doesn't help me so far. Here is my problem:

ENV:

1. On server side use Node with MongoDB and files storing in mongo. I
   use GridFS to pickup files and sent to the client.
2. I use  Nginx as web server

I have a  tag and need the video plays looping on the client. What I found, that Chrome is sending range request to the server:

```
GET /54c4d7c6849b10b54af4ac23.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: https://www.xxxx.com/en-GB/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1593613130.1422274087
Range: bytes=26104-3116024
```

This request I handle in gridFS and reply with partial content following:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 13:47:48 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 3089921
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Range: bytes 26104-3116024/3116025
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

But after that Chrome stops show video. What's wrong in there? 
May I miss something in response header?

Comment: Is there a possibility that you give us the url of your page (site) to test it ? And, did you have the same problem in other browsers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved
Unfortunatelly Chrome is not very detailed in what happens in request/response. The problem is that size matters, actually. When size declared in Header different from actual content size. chrome just drop it with no reason. To identify this I set up Fiddler and found that my gridFS sends wrong file part size. Upgrading Gridfs to latest 1.0.1 version does solve this problem.

Comment: This seems to be reason why it does not work on Chrome when using `Content-Range` with audio files - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226595/streaming-audio-in-node-js-with-content-range